# Synchronizing attribute from another layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I'm relatively new to GIS. I'm working on a map that has unsynchronized data. There are two layers: landuse and POI. Layer Landuse is polygon, consisting of several classes of digitized landuse. Layer POI consists of points from buildings that are within each landuse class. Each point has an attribute column that explains from which landuse class they come from. For example, if a POI is in "Industrial" landuse, then its attribute should also say "Industrial".

For some POI, its attribute-landuse does not match the layer-landuse. For example, a POI is within "Vegetation" landuse, yet, the POI has "Residential" attribute. I've been manually checking each POI to make sure they have the correct landuse attribute, but since I have thousands of POIs, I wonder if there is any way to quickly change the attribute of the POI to match the landuse it is in?

Comment: Use intersect, which will create new points feature class. Or Near followed by join field and field calculator and delete unwanted fields

Comment: I tried intersect and it worked. Thank you for the help